# Integrating JSF2 with Spring3 and Hibernate4 - applicationContext.xml error?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf-2

I'm trying to create a JSF2 application which uses Spring3 for the DI and hibernate to handle the persistence.

I'm stock on the following error and don't know how to proceed:

```
26/10/2012 1:57:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:647)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:685)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:272)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection refused: connect Nested exception: Connection refused: connect
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:78)
    ... 43 more
```

my `applicationContext.xml` is listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.techrro" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="view">
                    <bean class="com.myapp.util.ViewScope" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver">
        </property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/myapp">
        </property>
        <property name="username" value="mydb"></property>
        <property name="password" value="somepass"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
                <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>com/myapp/techrro/hibernate/UserOrderHist.hbm.xml
                </value>
                <value>com/myapp/techrro/hibernate/UserAccessHist.hbm.xml
                </value>
                <value>com/myapp/techrro/hibernate/User.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userOrderHistDAO" class="com.myapp.techrro.hibernate.userOrderHistDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userAccessHistDAO" class="com.myapp.techrro.hibernate.userAccessHistDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDAO" class="com.myapp.techrro.hibernate.userDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

### Update:

below are my mapping files, they were generated by myEclipse:

`User.hbm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd ">
<!-- 
    Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools
-->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.myapp.techrro.hibernate.User" table="User" schema="dbo" catalog="mydb">
        <id name="user_PK" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="user_PK" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="username" length="20" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="password" length="40" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="userRole" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="userRole" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="active" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="active" length="1" />
        </property>
        <property name="type" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="type" length="3" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="firstName" length="30" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="lastName" length="30" />
        </property>
        <set name="userOrderHistLog" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="user_PK" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.myapp.techrro.hibernate.userOrderHist" />
        </set>
        <set name="userAccessHistLog" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="user_PK" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.myapp.techrro.hibernate.userAccessHist" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

`UserOrderHist.hbm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd ">
<!-- 
    Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools
-->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.myapp.techrro.hibernate.userOrderHist" table="userOrderHist" schema="dbo" catalog="mydb">
        <id name="userOrderHis_PK" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="userOrderHis_PK" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user" class="com.myapp.techrro.hibernate.User" fetch="select">
            <column name="user_PK" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="action" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="action" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="prod" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="username" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="type" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="userRole" length="1" />
        </property>
        <property name="Updated" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="deleteFG" length="1" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

`UserAccessHist.hbm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd ">
<!-- 
    Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools
-->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.myapp.techrro.hibernate.userAccessHist" table="userAccessHist" schema="dbo" catalog="mydb">
        <id name="userAccessHistPK" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="userAccessHistPK" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user_PK" class="com.myapp.techrro.hibernate.User" fetch="select">
            <column name="adminUserPK" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="createdDate" type="java.sql.Timestamp">
            <column name="createdDate" length="23" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="accessDetail" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="accessDetail" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Can someone please possible causes of such error? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your stacktrace (`org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML`), the problem is most likely in one of your hibernate mapping XML files.

Update:
Now that you have posted your hibernate files, it appears that you have an extra space at the end of the DTDs.  Removing the trailing spaces should fix the problem.

Comment: not sure what can't be wrong there - they were generated by MyEclipse - I checked their DTD and points to valid location. I'll update my question with the mapping files included.

Comment: I googled and found that it might be related to the loading of the DTDs: http://programmingpanda.blogspot.com/2011/08/could-not-parse-configuration.html

Comment: the DTDs seem fine in my hbm.xml files - They point to valid and accessible xml.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me as being wrong.  There is an extra space after your DTD portion of the doctype.  It would be very annoying if that is the problem, but I would feel better knowing it isn't.  Second, could it be the paths to the mapping XMLs aren't correct?  I would expect a different exception in that case, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: OMG! removing the extra space fixed it! That's  2 hours i will never get back :( Thanks for pointing out . Update your initial answer and i will mark it as such. Thanks again mate

Comment: "they were generated by MyEclipse" <- I see the problem. Always be wary of tools that relies on automatic generation.